# android relativelayout two rows with column on the right

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to achieve a two rows on the left with a floating (right) TextView which will have a number. This is a listview item layout.

```
                               ____
___________________________   |    |
___________________________   |____|
```

So contents would be something like

```
LINE ONE CAN SOMETIMES BE LONG   £2000.00
line two
```

However the £2000.00 (which is larger text size) is either overlapped with code sample below or by using `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row1"` it's basically sitting next to row1 and sometimes goes on next line if row1 is long. It should always be in one line.

Can anyone help?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightcol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#cc0000"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With this the right column text overlaps row1

Thanks for checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`android:layout_weight` will be useful for achieving your desired layout (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)). Instead of 50dp you could use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for the right side text view. The other TextViews will adjust to fill the remaining space. You can use `android:singleLine="true"` to limit your TextViews so that they don't wrap.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you're set on using RelativeLayout this should work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="6dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:text="This text can be very, very long"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightcol"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightcol"
        android:text="$2000000000000.00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#cc0000"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:text="Second line of text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightcol"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Added `android:singleLine="true"` but it doesn't really help since amount floats above row1. I know this can be achieved with two LinearLayouts but I am a little fixated on getting relativelayout to do the job with minimal xml. If not then I can always revert to LL. Thanks again

Comment: Add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightcol"` to the two left text views.

Comment: `android:layout_toLeftOf` did the job. I had to make the two rows `fill_parent` and `gravity` left otherwise it was right aligned. Thanks dude. I'll upvote but the current answer doesn't answer question so please update so I can mark it as correct answer